# Win 7, Eclipse, 64-bit, JRE, WTF? :)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java, eclipse

So I just set up Windows 7 64-bit on a new box and I'd like to install Eclipse and Flex Builder to get some work done.

Unfortunately, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed in a 64-bit environment. From googling around I've seen it said that you need a 64-bit JRE to run the 64-bit Eclipse, and that there is a 64-bit JRE but that it requires and AMD processor which I don't have (running an i7). Then in various threads there are various broken links to some mythical JRE that should solve all of my problems, but it seems to have been pulled from everywhere.

So, as simply as possible: I would like to set up Flex Builder 3 as an Eclipse Plug-in running in 64-bit in Windows 7. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website probably states that the JRE for 64-bit Windows 7 uses the [x86-64 instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) (sometimes called AMD64), which an Intel i7 CPU definitely supports.

Comment: Thanks, actually, that helped. I'm up and running now with Eclipse. Now I learn that FB3 doesn't support Eclipse 3.5, so it's on to FB4 Beta... oh boy...